# Why do separate RUNs in Dockerfile fail to build but chained RUNs does successfully?

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

COPY sources sources

RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45
RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core -Source C:\sources\sxs

ENTRYPOINT powershell
```

Building an image using above Dockerfile always fails due a timeout error on the second Add-WindowsFeature command.

> This operation returned because the timeout period expired. (0x5b4)

However, it builds successfully if I write the Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

COPY sources sources

RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45; \
                        Add-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core -Source C:\sources\sxs

ENTRYPOINT powershell
```

I can't find any information in the documentation why having two separate RUNS for the same command (i.e. `powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature ...`) in the Dockerfile would not work.

Comment: might be just command doesnt return too fast, there are no such limitations (not being able to have 2 run command for similar things)

Comment: My actual Dockerfile has other RUN commands included and the pattern I am noticing is that only the first RUN command builds successfully. I tried adding a different RUN command above the chained Add-WindowsFeature in my question, and the first RUN command built successfully. The chained Add-WindowsFeature command timed out.

Any idea why "command doesn't return too fast"?

Comment: well, its just my speculation. i cannot test it. easiest way to test it - try another pc. try a vm with docker, try hosted docker, etc.